# coreadm solaris command equvalent in linux?

Tags: linux

what is the equivalent of **coreadm** solaris command in linux

Comment: Users of Linux who know the answer, but *don't* know Solaris won't be able to help you unless you say *what* `coreadm` accomplishes...

Comment: `coreadm` does more than what I'll outline; with respect to what @venkat is asking: pretty much everything you can do in Linux through `/etc/sysctl.conf` (see http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern) can be accomplished with `coreadm`, with one important difference: `coreadm` alters those settings for child processes of the process that called coreadm.

Answer (score 4):

coreadm allows you to configure various aspects of core file generation (naming patterns, logging, ...) on Solaris systems. Linux isn't as feature rich here and only allows you to
customize the name of the core files. This can be done by writing a format string into 
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern.

See man 5 core for the details.

Comment: In more recent kernels (> 2.6.23) you can also change which types of mappings are included in core dumps (`/proc/<pid>/coredump_filter`).

Comment: @caf: sweet. didn't knew that one!

Comment: That's disappointing ... both of these solutions kinda suck.  The kernel one requires admin privileges and would do it for everything that runs, whereas the `/proc/<pid>` one could only be done after a process is spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method [discussed here](http://timetobleed.com/an-obscure-kernel-feature-to-get-more-info-about-dying-processes/) (see `man -s5 core`, under **Piping core dumps to a program**
), you could do something along these lines (with root permissions of course):

```
 ~ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/path/to/a/script some arguments
```

... and put together a script that reads the coredump on `stdin` and writes it out to a file whose path is dictated in some other fashion.

From a security standpoint, this seems like a very scary thing to do though.  There's a lot of potential gotchas.

As mentioned on the [sigquit](http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern) blog, it looks like changes to `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` are impermanent and you'd need to make changes to `/etc/sysctl.conf` by editing it directly, or using `sysctl`.